# Haskell merge sort inversions

Tags: haskell, sorting

I'm working on a task from the one of Coursera programming courses. The purpose is to estimate the amount of inversions that are required to sort the array of numbers.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Also I'm trying to learn some Haskell basics, here is my solution:

```
fsthalf :: [a] -> [a]
fsthalf xs = take (length xs `div` 2) xs

sndhalf :: [a] -> [a]
sndhalf xs = drop (length xs `div` 2) xs

union :: ([Int], Int) -> ([Int], Int) -> ([Int], Int)
union (a, ac) (b, bc) = (a++b, ac+bc)

merge :: ([Int], Int) -> ([Int], Int) -> ([Int], Int)
merge ([], ac) (bs, bc) = (bs, ac + bc)
merge (as, ac) ([], bc) = (as, ac + bc)
merge (a:as, ac) (b:bs, bc)
  | a <= b = ([a], 0) `union` merge (as, ac) (b:bs, bc)
  | otherwise = ([b], length(a:as)) `union` merge (a:as, ac) (bs, bc)


mergeSort :: ([Int], Int) -> ([Int], Int)
mergeSort (s, c)
  | length s `elem` [0, 1]  = (s, c)
  | otherwise = merge (mergeSort (fsthalf s, c)) (mergeSort (sndhalf s, c))


main :: IO()
main = do
  _ <- readLn :: IO Int
  rawValues <- getLine
  let intValues = map read $ words rawValues :: [Int]
  print $ snd $ mergeSort (intValues, 0)
```

It seems to work properly, but exceeds time limits. It takes from 9 to 10 seconds to sort the longest possible list of integers (100000 values), while the limit is 6 seconds. Could anyone please point out some possible optimizations for this solution.

Comment: Please don't use images of text. They're not accessible. Instead, type in the text itself.

Answer (score 4):

General review tips:

- It'd be better to document your code. In particular functions like

  ```
  union :: ([Int], Int) -> ([Int], Int) -> ([Int], Int)
  ```

  need documentation - it's not clear which `Int` has what purpose at all without examining the source.
- Some of your functions are polymorphic (`sndhalf`), others not. Why? I'd suggest to have all types consistent. Either just sort `Int`s, or make the types as generic as possible, for example

  ```
  union :: (Ord a) => ([a], Int) -> ([a], Int) -> ([a], Int)
  ```

  Notice how this generality also makes the types easier to understand.
- I'd suggest to wrap list + its inversion count into a `newtype` such as:

  ```
  newtype List a = List [a] Int
  ```

  This makes the code better structured, and also allows you to use [smart
  constructors](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors), if you decide
  so.
- Investigate Haskell's
  [`sort`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#sort)
  for inspiration.

Now specific to performance:
- For each pass you traverse the list several times,
which can impact the performance considerably. In particular: `take` and
`length` in `fsthalf`, the same in `sndhalf`. Also `length` in `mergeSort`. This
makes it 5 traversals before the merging pass. I'd try to reduce this number.

- Matching on `length` is wasteful, if you need just to distinguish if it's 0 or 1, you traverse the whole list needlessly:

  ```
  mergeSort (s, c) | length s `elem` [0, 1]  = (s, c)
  ```

  Instead:

  ```
  mergeSort ([], _) = ([], 0)
  mergeSort (xs@[_], _) = (xs, 1)
  ...
  ```
- Make sure you're compiling with [`-O`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Performance/GHC#Use_optimisation).

I hope this helps!